# replace method works without html formatting but with formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the color of the text when a user clicks on a cell value. It seems like when I try to use the formatting in my html, it stopped working, however, it works totally fine without formatting. The JSFiddles will help you in understanding what I am taking about. Before that, I would like to mention few things:

1. When I am not formatting, I am just using

   `<div id='jqxPanel' style=" font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana;"> My content here  </div>` and `var text = panel.text();`
2. When I am using formatting, I am using

   `<div id='jqxPanel' style=" font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana;"><div style="margin: 10px;"><pre>My content here </pre></div></div>` and `var text = panel.html();`

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b35q3gxv/53/) without any formatting and a non working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b35q3gxv/51/) with formatting feature. How can I make the non working JSFiddle work properly so that I can see the highlighted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b35q3gxv/54/)

```
$("#jqxgrid").on("cellclick", function (event) 
                   {
    var value = event.args.value;
    var color = "#FF0000";
    var highlighted =                  
        text.replace( new RegExp(value, 'ig' ), '<span style="color:' + color + ';">' + value + '</span>');

    panel.jqxPanel('clearcontent');
    panel.jqxPanel('append', highlighted);
  });
```

You're trying to replace " something " instead of "something" (notice the blanks). And you're doing this both in the search string and the replacement.

Also, the replace function is case-sensitive. I added a RegExp to make it case-insensitive.

BUT, this is just an example, you can see that it replaces the text with the case of the button, so "PATIENT" will be "Patient" highlighted.

Comment: Thanks Franx. What if I don't want to keep it case-insensitive? Also, is it a good practice to replace the text with the case of the button?

Comment: I think the best is finding a way to keep the case of the replaced text (the only problem i can see with this). And no, i don't think so, unless you're 100% sure the cases of the button and the text's words are the same (but for this, you'll have to make all upper or lower case). Sorry for my bad english.